# pass different conditions to linq where

Tags: c#, linq

I have two conditions to the following linq, `IsThere` and `Conditional` are provided by the user. 
They can be true, false, or "not given".

```
var result = (from DataRow dt in resultForfaultStat.Rows
              select new fault_StatisticsViewModel{
                Name = dt["name"].ToString(),
                SureName = float.Parse(dt["fname"].ToString()),
                IsThere = Boolean.Parse(dt["is_there"].ToString()),
                Conditional = Boolean.Parse(dt["good_or_bad"].ToString())
              })
              .Where(s => s.IsThere == true && s.Conditional == true)
              .ToList();
```

How should I manage to pass these all dynamically?

Comment: Can you try to explain me your attempt?

Comment: @MarcoSalerno mine is very basic var finalresult= result.Where(s => s.Conditional== x && s.IsThere== y) i get x,y from user,which is true or false

Comment: @mortezasol your solution looks pretty fine for me

Comment: `.Where(s => s.IsThere == true && s.Conditional == true)` in this line if you replace those with variable? There is no null value for bool so you can't have none of them given .. Perhaps `bool?`?

Comment: In addition to the duplicate: assuming that value is optional **for simple cases** you can also rewrite it as: `Where(x => (!isThereValue.HasValue && x.IsThere == isThereValue.Value) && ...)` where `isThereValue` is `bool?` (with `null` to indicate that comparison isn't required)

Comment: @AdrianoRepett  you are right,if i get string from user i cant compare it with bool,if i get bool,what should i do with null?!the solution is your last suggestion?

Comment: @DragandDrop your solution ?

Comment: @mortezasol if user enters a string then you just need to parse it, something like `bool? TryParseUserBoolean(string text) { if (Boolean.TryParse(text, out bool value) { return value; } return null; }`

Comment: AdrianoRepett comment and mine are pointing in the exact same direction. You need a `bool?`. As you comment about getting the value as string you can simply  `if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(userString_IsThere)&& bool.TryParse(userString_IsThere, out bool variableIsThere)){
 result = result.where( s => s.IsThere == variableIsThere);
}`

Comment: @mortezasol, as you were confuse by your issue, your question was really confusing. You should read the guide line [ask]. Here you gave the code too soon, and didn't spend enought time to explain what you were trying, and the context you were working. Where you could be getting those variable from, their type, their values were important information. The clearer you are the easier it get. Most of the time following this guideline you will find your answer simply by redacting a clear question. without the need to post the question.

Comment: @Heinzi : IMO, Answer for this question won't apply to the duplicate target. 
Even if both have really close title, the second part of the question clarify the fact that op has issue handeling bool user input (user enter yes , no or nothing).
 While the ohter question don't have that part and will make adding a answer about parsing an user input really weird.

Comment: @DragandDrop: As far as I can see, the OP has two issues: (1) How to parse yes/no/unknown user input into a suitable data structure and (2) how to use conditional where clauses in LINQ. (1) has only been revealed in the comments (after a lot of back-and-forth), so I still think that the dupe target is appropriate (for (2)). I also don't think that having (1)+(2) together makes a good SO question likely to help other users.

Comment: i also found this question useful and not duplicated